# Does a Python strip() on a split() string do anything?

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, strip

Based on some experiments, it appears to me that the following Python v2.7 code:

```
def lookup_pattern(pattern, file_containing_patterns):
  for line in file_containing_patterns:
    splits = line.split()
    if splits:
      if (pattern == splits[0]):
        return map(lambda x: x.strip(), splits[1:])
  return None
```

Could be simplified as follows to drop the `map` of `strip()`:

```
def lookup_pattern(pattern, file_containing_patterns):
  for line in file_containing_patterns:
    splits = line.split()
    if splits:
      if (pattern == splits[0]):
        return splits[1:]
  return None
```

I believe this is true because the `split()` should remove all white space and thus the `strip()` would be a no-op.

Are there any cases where in the above two are not identical in effect, if so, what are they?

Comment: `split()` split a string followed by space, it doesn't remove white spaces.

Comment: Eh? Sure it does. `>>> 'foo '.split()` -> `['foo']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) indicates that `split` with the implicit whitespace delimiter (that is, `split()` without further arguments) will clear out any "empty tokens" and you don't need to strip anything. As any consecutive series of whitespace could be interpreted as a list of empty tokens delimited by space, that'll mean the strings get trimmed automatically.

If, instead you split with a different delimiter or implicitly defined the whitespace, this may happen:

```
' 1  2   3  '.split()
=> ['1', '2', '3']

'  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1)
=> ['1', '2   3  ']
```